# SAS: reading dates with different formats

Tags: sas

In SAS,  how to read the following dates with different formats? (especially 01/05/2018 and 1/6/2018)

01/05/2018
1/6/2018
Jan 05 2018
Jan 6 2018

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ANYDTDTM` informat will parse most varieties of human readable date, time or datetime representations into a SAS datetime value.  The `datepart` function of that value will return the SAS date value thereof.

The `ANYDTDTE` informat will also parse a variety of date, time or datetime representations and return the date part implicitly. However it fails on some of your data items where `ANYDTDTM` does not.

```
data _null_;

  input 
    @1 a_datetime_value anydtdtm. 
    @1 a_date_value anydtdte.
    ;

  hot_date = datepart(a_datetime_value);

  put 
    '_infile_   ' _infile_
  / 'anydtdtm.  ' a_datetime_value datetime16. 
  / 'datepart() ' hot_date yymmdd10. 
  / 'anydtdte.  ' a_date_value yymmdd10. 
  /;

datalines;
01/05/2018
1/6/2018
Jan 05 2018
Jan 6 2018
run;
```

==== LOG ====

```
_infile_   01/05/2018
anydtdtm.  05JAN18:00:00:00
datepart() 2018-01-05
anydtdte.           .

_infile_   1/6/2018
anydtdtm.  06JAN18:00:00:00
datepart() 2018-01-06
anydtdte.  2018-01-06

_infile_   Jan 05 2018
anydtdtm.  05JAN18:00:00:00
datepart() 2018-01-05
anydtdte.           .

_infile_   Jan 6 2018
anydtdtm.  06JAN18:00:00:00
datepart() 2018-01-06
anydtdte.           .
```

Read the SAS documentation and conference papers for a greater exploration of the `ANYDT**` family of informats.

Comment: `ANYDTDTE.` works fine on those values, as long as you tell it to read the whole string.  The default width is only 9 characters whereas for `ANYDTDTM.` the default width is 19.

Comment: Thank you Richard and Tom. If I use anydtdte15. in the input statement, anydtdte. and datepart() are exactly the same here. Thank you!